# Check value in a variable using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check value in a variable using JavaScript with `if` condition. In these case value of the variable `location` is `var location="Banglore"`. But every time go to else part.

My code is

```
  var location="Banglore";
  if(typeof(location)== "Bangalore")
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?      q=Bangalore&units=metric";
   }
  else if(typeof(location) == "Chennai")
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?q=Chennai&units=metric";
   }
 else if(typeof(location) == "Cochi")
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?  q=Cochi&units=metric";
   }
 else 
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?q=Pune&units=metric";
   }
```

In these code always go to else part, i.e. location ==pune condition.Any body help me

Comment: This may have just been copied incorrectly, but there is a typo in your first line. I think it should read `var location = "Bangalore"`.

Comment: Well, `typeof` will **never** return `"Chennai"`. What do you think `typeof` does? Hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: You also may have a conflict with the pre-defined global `window.location`.  If this code you show is in the global namespace, then change your `location` variable to a different name.

Comment: I'd really suggest some basic Javascript training.  At least look up what `typeof` does or read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: get the basics clear first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the location as 'Banglore' and the 'if' condition is 'Bangalore'.

Comment: Plus the thing with `typeof` and possibly the whitespaces in the query are incorrect, too.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you have wrong values for check.

```
var location="Banglore";
  if(location == "Bangalore") // extra `a` after `g`
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?      q=Bangalore&units=metric";
   }
  else if(typeof(location) == "Chennai") // typeof gives here "string" as result
      //so your condition evaluates as
      // "string" == "Chennai", and so on for the rest,
      // hence it always goes to else block
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?q=Chennai&units=metric";
   }
```

Also don't declare variable inside local blocks, if you are gonna use it outside that given block, here it is `data_file` declared inside if..else block.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, You have comparing wrong syntax,

```
var location="Banglore";
  if(location == "Bangalore") // this should be location == "Banglore"
   {
```

Second thing is,

Why do you use `typeof()` to check other cities? As far as my knowledge says, you should use

```
var location="Banglore";
  if(location == "Banglore")
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?q=Bangalore&units=metric";
   }
  else if(location == "Chennai")
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?q=Chennai&units=metric";
   }
 else if(location == "Cochi")
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?q=Cochi&units=metric";
   }
 else 
   {
      var data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
      find?q=Pune&units=metric";
   }
```

NOTE : you may have to remove the white spaces in the queries as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use switch statement instead, this is what it's meant for...

```
var location = "Banglore",
    data_file = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?units=metric&q=";

switch (location) {
    case "Bangalore":
        data_file += "Bangalore";
        break;
    case "Chennai":
        data_file += "Chennai";
        break;
    case "Cochi":
        data_file += "Cochi";
        break;
    default:
        data_file += "Pune";
}
```